# Android Studio emulator cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument

Tags: android, emulation, ram

I’m unable to launch an emulator in android studio due to the following error:

emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
emulator: device fd:620
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument

When installing HAXM I set the memory to 1024MB and the emulator (using Nexus 5) has been configured to only use 256MB of RAM :

[image]

I’ve tried increasing/decreasing the RAM setting but it appears to have no affect with the same error message appearing each time.

I don’t understanding why this is happening and have tried installing different versions of Android Studio. I’m currently running 1.3.2 which is the version my colleague is successfully using on the same spec PC (4GB ram, Windows 7 32 bit).

The error indicates that the emulator is trying to increase its RAM size to 1GB dispite it being set to 256MB.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that down grading the system image from Marshmallow (API 23) to KitKat (API 19) has resolved this issue. Its been stable for a week and the emulator isnt trying to increae the RAM size.

Comment: Same problem and after several tries of several other solutions this also worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried to change the Emulator's OS (System image)?
Try to change to Lollipop with API -> Level 22, ABI -> x86, Target -> Android 5.1 (with Google API)

In this window, you can see and download this specific version - among many others - by checking 'Show downloadable system images'

Hope this helps
Chris Martin